# slideDown new text by hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m looking for some help with jQuery.

I´ve got an overlayer with 10 buttons on the left side and a description text on the right side. When I hover over a button the description text changes. So far so good.

What I want to achieve is a transition between those text changes. When the user hovers over the next button, I want the new text to slide in from above and to push the old text away (to the bottom).

**Button**

```
<a href="#" id="text1" class="myButton">Text1</a>
```

**Description Div**

```
<div id="description">
 <p id="descriptiontext">Hover over a category</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#text1").hover(function(){
$('#descriptiontext').slideDown('fast', function(){
    $('#descriptiontext').text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.");
    });
});
```

This doesn't do anything. Could you help me?
Kind regards!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle to show the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You were mistaken between `slideUp` and `slideDown`.

First replace slideDown :

```
$('#descriptiontext').slideUp(...);
```

Then slide down your new content :

```
$('#descriptiontext').text("Lorem ... voluptua.").slideDown('fast');
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/red7ju7s/

---

Anyway, I think you **should not** handle your texts using jQuery (I mean not the real text content). Try to put all your descriptions in divs in your content and hide them. Use jQuery to pick the text and display it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a text "pushing" another text, you need to use at least 2 `div`.

Here's an example :

```js
$('button').hover(function() {
  var $selected = $('div.selected'),
      id = 'text' + $(this).data('text');
  
  if ($selected.length && $selected.attr('id') == id) {
    return;  
  }
  
  // Hide the current text
  $selected.slideUp('slow').removeClass('selected');
  
  // Display the new text
  $('#' + id).slideDown('slow').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

#right {
  float : left;
  width: 200px;
}

#right div {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
  <button data-text="1">Text 1</button>
  <button data-text="2">Text 2</button>
  <button data-text="3">Text 3</button>
  <button data-text="4">Text 4</button>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="text1">Text 1 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
  
  <div id="text2">Text 2 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
  
  <div id="text3">Text 3 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
  
  <div id="text4">Text 4 Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
</div>
```